# React Render section from external function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In order to reuse code, I want to render the following section of my `<SectionList>`component from an external function:

Component class:

```
<SectionList
              renderSectionHeader={this._renderBasicInfoSectionHeader}
              sections={[
                {
                  title: profileConstants.BASIC_INFO_DESCRIPTION,
                  data: [{}],
                  renderItem: ({item, index}) =>
                      <View style={{padding: 15, flexDirection: "row"}}>
                        <View style={{flex: 4}}>
                          <ReadMore
                              style={{padding: 5}}
                              numberOfLines={3}
                              renderTruncatedFooter={this._renderTruncatedFooter}
                              renderRevealedFooter={this._renderRevealedFooter}
                              onReady={this._handleTextReady}
                          >
                            <Text style={{padding: 5}}>
                              {this.props.description}
                            </Text>
                          </ReadMore>
                        </View>
                      </View>

                }
```

I tried to render it from an internal component function and it works fine:

```
  renderDescription = (description) => { return {
    title: profileConstants.BASIC_INFO_DESCRIPTION,
        data: [{}],
        renderItem: ({item, index}) =>
        <View style={{padding: 15, flexDirection: "row"}}>
          <View style={{flex: 4}}>
            <ReadMore
                style={{padding: 5}}
                numberOfLines={3}
                renderTruncatedFooter={this._renderTruncatedFooter}
                renderRevealedFooter={this._renderRevealedFooter}
                // onReady={handleTextReady}
            >
              <Text style={{padding: 5}}>
                {description}
              </Text>
            </ReadMore>
          </View>
        </View>

  }};

   ...

  render() {
    const description = this.props.description;
    <SectionList
         renderSectionHeader={this._renderBasicInfoSectionHeader}
            sections={[
                this.renderDescription(description),
```

But if I am extracting that function in other file and I import it to the component, it renders undefined. Any solution?:

../Common/CommonSections.js:

```
export const renderDescription = (description) =>  {return {
  title: profileConstants.BASIC_INFO_DESCRIPTION,
  data: [{}],
  renderItem: ({item, index}) =>
      <View style={{padding: 15, flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <View style={{flex: 4}}>
          <ReadMore
              style={{padding: 5}}
              numberOfLines={3}
              renderTruncatedFooter={this._renderTruncatedFooter}
              renderRevealedFooter={this._renderRevealedFooter}
              // onReady={handleTextReady}
          >
            <Text style={{padding: 5}}>
              {description}
            </Text>
          </ReadMore>
        </View>
      </View>

}};
```

Component:

```
 import {renderDescription} from "../common/CommonSections";

  render() {
    const description = this.props.description;
    return (
        <View>
          <SectionList
              renderSectionHeader={this._renderBasicInfoSectionHeader}
              sections={[
                renderDescription(description),
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this code part:

```
export const renderDescription = (description) =>  {return {
  title: profileConstants.BASIC_INFO_DESCRIPTION,
  data: [{}],
  renderItem: ({item, index}) =>
      <View style={{padding: 15, flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <View style={{flex: 4}}>
          <ReadMore
              style={{padding: 5}}
              numberOfLines={3}
              renderTruncatedFooter={this._renderTruncatedFooter}
              renderRevealedFooter={this._renderRevealedFooter}
              // onReady={handleTextReady}
          >
            <Text style={{padding: 5}}>
              {description}
            </Text>
          </ReadMore>
        </View>
      </View>

}};
```

Have you extracted `renderDescription` with the different functions (_renderTruncatedFooter, _renderRevealedFooter), constant (profileConstants), and imported the different React-Native components (View, Text, ReadMore)?

Comment: Yes, but still the samw result

Comment: Can you post this new file you created (Common/CommonSections.js)?